# Is there a formula for n/rad(n)

Tags: number-theory

Are there any known formulas for $n/\mathrm{rad}(n)$; summation or otherwise, that do not involve the Mobius function? Where may I find a list of formulas for this function of any type?

Here $\mathrm{rad}(n)$ is defined as the product of all (distinct) prime factors of $n$.

Comment: Correction, Here rad(n) is defined as the product of the distinct prime factors of n. This is also known as the square-free kernel of n or the largest square-free divisor.

Comment: You can get some information on an average of sorts of the radical at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160059/estimation-of-sum-n-leq-x-fracknn-with-kn-the-squarefree-kern

Comment: If $n=\prod_{j=1}^k p_j^{a_j}$ where the $p_j$ are distinct primes and $a_j\ge1$, then $n/rad(n) = \prod_{j=1}^k p_j^{a_j-1}$. Is this formula suitable for you? If not, what properties do you want the formula to have?

Comment: For example, define a multiplicative function $g(n)$ by declaring that $g(p)=0$ for any prime $p$, while $g(p^a) = p^{a-2}(p-1)$ for any $a\ge2$. Then $n/rad(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} g(d)$. Is that suitable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question but,
$n/rad(n)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lfloor{\frac{j^n}{n}}\rfloor-\lfloor{\frac{j^n-1}{n}}\rfloor $. This is because the two floor functions are just a characteristic equation that can only be $1$ or $0$ depending on whether or not $n|j^n$. The exponents in the prime factorization of $j^n$ are going to be larger than the exponents of the prime factorization of $n$, because $j$ is raised to the power of $n$. So, only the prime factors of $n$ and $j$ matter in whether or not $n|j^n$. Considering the factors, $n$ can only divide if $j$ is a multiple of $rad(n)$, so the sum is counting the multiples of $rad(n)\leq n$, but this is just $n/rad(n)$. This is probably exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A formula is give at [OEIS:Radical of n, product of distinct prime factors of n](https://oeis.org/wiki/Radical_of_n,_product_of_distinct_prime_factors_of_n):

> Multiplicative with $a(p^{\alpha}) \,=\, p^{\alpha - 1}, \, $thus with $n \,=\, \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(n)} p_{i}^{\alpha_i}, \,$ we have
>   $$
>     \frac{n}{{\rm rad}(n)} = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(n)} p_{i}^{\alpha_i - 1}, \, 
> $$

where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors.